# How to force the opening of UNetBootin?

Tags: startup

I'm trying to install [UNetBootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) for a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012). However, I got this message when I tried to open it. Could anyone be able to tell me what I can do to force its opening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on it in Finder and then clicking "Open".